# Scala, Spark: find element-wise average of N maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I have N maps (Map[String, Double]) each having the same set of keys. Let's say something like the following:

```
map1 = ("elem1": 2.0, "elem2": 4.0, "elem3": 3.0)

map2 = ("elem1": 4.0, "elem2": 1.0, "elem3": 1.0)

map3 = ("elem1": 3.0, "elem2": 10.0, "elem3": 2.0)
```

I need to return a new map with element-wise average of those input maps:

```
resultMap = ("elem1": 3.0, "elem2": 5.0, "elem3": 2.0)
```

What's the cleanest way to do that in scala? Preferrably without using extra external libraries.

This all happens in Spark*. Thus any answers suggesting spark-specific usage could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to convert all Maps to Seqs, union them to a single Seq, group by key and take the average of values:

```
val maps = Seq(map1, map2, map3)

maps.map(_.toSeq).reduce(_++_).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).sum/x.length)

// res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(elem1 -> 3.0, elem3 -> 2.0, elem2 -> 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged with *apache-spark* you can get your desired output by combining the maps into `RDD[Map[String, Double]]` as

```
scala>     val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map("elem1"-> 2.0, "elem2"-> 4.0, "elem3"-> 3.0),Map("elem1"-> 4.0, "elem2"-> 1.0, "elem3"-> 1.0),Map("elem1"-> 3.0, "elem2"-> 10.0, "elem3"-> 2.0)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24
```

Then you can use `flatMap` to *flatten* the entries of *maps* into *individual rows* and use `groupBy` function with *key* and `sum` the *grouped values* and `devide` it with the size of the *grouped maps*. You should get Your desired output as

```
scala> rdd.flatMap(row => row).groupBy(kv => kv._1).mapValues(values => values.map(value => value._2).sum/values.size)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double)] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at mapValues at <console>:27

scala> res0.foreach(println)
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 4](elem2,5.0)
(elem3,2.0)
(elem1,3.0)
```

Hope the answer is helpful